# Jquery toggle class on previous item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements of which I want to toggle a class with the help of arrows. Two items should always have the class "active". Clicking "next" arrow should result in the two next items getting the class "active", the the two current ones getting the class removed. Clicking the "previous" arrow should result in the previous two items getting the class "active", and the current ones getting the class removed.

At the moment I can get it to work with the "next" arrow, i.e. the classes keeps getting added accordingly. It is however the "previous" arrow that doesn't work properly. The class of the first item doesn't get removed at all. [See my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/EllinorBergman/3r603own/)

Code:

```
$('.quote:first-of-type').addClass('active');
$('.quote:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('active');


$('.arrow-right').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass(function(){
    if($(this).is('li:last-of-type') ) {
        $('.quote:first-of-type').addClass('active');
        $('.quote:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll("li:lt(2)").addClass('active');
        return 'active';
    }
    })
});

$('.arrow-left').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass(function(){
        if($(this).is('li:first-of-type')) {                
            $('.quote:last-of-type').addClass('active');
            $('.quote:nth-last-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');

        } else {
            $(this).prevAll("li:lt(2)").addClass('active');
            return 'active';
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** `.arrow-left` **class click**

**Live Demo** **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/gn9819bm/)**

```
$('.arrow-left').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass(function(){
            if(($(this).is('li:first-of-type')) || ($(this).is('li:nth-of-type(2)')) )   {              
                $('.quote:last-of-type').addClass('active');
                $('.quote:nth-last-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
                //$(this).removeClass('active');
                $('.quote:first-of-type').removeClass('active');
                $('.quote:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).prevAll("li:lt(2)").addClass('active');
        $('.quote:last-of-type').removeClass('active');
                $('.quote:nth-last-of-type(2)').removeClass('active');
                return 'active';
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Why are you doing this inside a `removeClass` callback? IMHO you're doing the active/inactive-toggling unnecessarily twice.

Answer (score 0):

I found your approach interesting and it has given me an insight into some jquery selectors I did not know about. I thinkyour issue might result from the fact that you're modifying the underlying data structure via your removeClass function. The first time it is called it removes an active class such that the second time it is called (on the 2nd active element) it is working on different data from the first time. So the selector first-of-type could well be being matched both times.

A nice approach for this might be to introduce a bit more immutability on the classes attached to the underlying list by:

1. Extract the indexes of the active items
2. Do your logic about what should be the next set of active elements without modifying the DOM by using jquery selectors to traverse the list
3. Remove all the active classes in one go
4. Update the DOM with the new classes

Here's a fiddle forked from yours showing that in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/wpv10j12/

Here's the key code showing the steps 1-4. It's a bit more verbose than the concise version in the fiddle:

```
$('.arrow-right').click(function() {
    // 1. Extract the index of the first active item
    var active = $(".quote").index($(".active").eq(0));

    // 2. Do the logic. Check we're not at the end and if not get the index
    // of the element we want to set to active by jumping 2 forwards.
    var end = $(".quote").length - 2;
    if (active < end) {
        var next = active + 2;
        // 3. Remove all active classes
        $(".active").toggleClass("active");
        // 4. Add the new ones in one go.
        $(".quote").eq(next).addClass("active").next().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you mix class selectors with type selectors. I suggest to use either one or the other. Beside that I would avoid to add CSS classes inside of `removeClass`.

You can try this for your left click function:

```
$('.arrow-left').click(function() {
    var firstActive = $('.active:first');
    $('.active').removeClass();
    if ($(firstActive).is('li:first-of-type')) {
      var last = $('li:last');
      $(last).addClass('active');
      $(last).prev('li').addClass('active');
    }  else {
      $(firstActive).prevAll("li:lt(2)").addClass('active');
    }
});
```